# Compound unique index not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I try to create compount index like this:

```
@CompoundIndexes(
value = [
        CompoundIndex(
            name = "entity_index",
            unique = true,
            def = "{'entityId':1, 'type': 1}"
        )
    ]
)

data class Subscription(
    @field:Id
    val id: String,

    val entityId: String,

    val type: EntityType,
)
```

but when I save the same model with equal entityId and type with ReactiveMongoTemplate exception isn't throwned

Answer (score -1):

Should use insert with reactiveMongoTemplate and index will work.